# Active X error 429

Tags: excel, activex, powerpoint

I have a 2010 PP presentation that calls a 97-2000 excel graph, which references stored procedures and does some data retrieval via sql.

When trying to call this document I'm getting a 429 error. Upon debug, the following code is highlighted.

```
Set appPP = GetObject(, "PowerPoint.Application")
```

vb is not a skillset of mine so plugging through as best I can, any help gratefully received.

Comment: This Microsoft article might help https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/kb/828550 - Also can you post some more of the code before that line?

Answer (score 0):

Try this instead:

```
Sub Test()
    Dim oPPT As Object
    Set oPPT = CreateObject("PowerPoint.Application")
    If oPPT Is Nothing Then
        MsgBox "No luck"
    Else
        MsgBox oPPT.version
        oPPT.quit
        Set oPPT = Nothing
    End If
End Sub
```